# Django admin custom inline fails with "Please Correct the Error Below"

Tags: django

I have a model class where i am using the django admin and it has a few inline forms.  I cannot save the change form for this model.  It always complains with "Please correct the error below"  even though there is no error highlighted on the page.

I have narrowed it down to the inline that is causing problems: HorizontalInline When i remove this one everything works.

Here are the relevant fields of my model:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class HorizontalInterface(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,)    
    us_equip = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, related_name='upstream')
    ds_equip = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, related_name='downstream')
```

Here are the relevant fields of my admin.py:

```
class HorizontalInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HorizontalInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = HorizontalInterface.objects.filter(Q(us_equip=self.instance) | Q(ds_equip=self.instance))

class HorizontalInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = HorizontalInterface
    formset = HorizontalInlineFormSet    
    show_change_link = True
    extra = 0
    fk_name = 'us_equip'

class EquipmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'description')


    inlines = [        
    HorizontalInline
    ]
```

I believe the complexity that it cannot handle is related to the fact that my horizontal interface model has two Equipment foreign keys and i would like to display all interfaces both upstream and downstream related to the equipment in question but also be able to edit them and save the equipment.

Any ideas how i can fix the save on my equipment model?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i have the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: I was having the same trouble and the issue was resolved when I removed the custom `id` field I had defined on the intermediate model.